# electron-rebuild doesn't use correct NODE_MODULE_VERSION

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-rebuild

I'm trying to target an electron installation with version 13.4.0 and Node version v14.16.0. However, when I run `electron-rebuild` on my file it builds for `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` for 83 (used by Node 14) and not the required 89 (used by electron). Here are some relevant files:

`binding.gyp`:

```py
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "tuxphones",
            "sources": ["main.cpp"],
            "cflags_cc": [
                "-std=c++17"
            ],
            "libraries": [
                "-lopus",
                "-lpulse"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14-buster-slim

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 make libpulse-dev libopus-dev g++

RUN mkdir /build
WORKDIR /build
COPY package.json /build/

RUN npm install
COPY ./native/ /build/
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "tuxphones",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Tuxphones.plugin.js",
  "scripts": {
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^13.4.0",
    "electron-rebuild": "^3.2.5"
  },
  "author": "ImTheSquid",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

How should I fix this so that I can build my module correctly against module version 89?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `#include` statement in my C++ file was including the system's Node library over the specific one for Electron.

I changed this:

```cpp
#include<node/node.h>
```

To this:

```cpp
#include<node.h>
```